# run query in AQL in Aersopike Docker container outside the container

Tags: docker, aerospike, aql

I have an aerospike docker container
and I want for some reason to run a query in AQL from outside this container
I know that this command can reach to AQL

```
docker exec -it <aerospike container name> bash -c aql
```

but I do not know how to execute a query

Answer (score 2):

After you run:

`docker exec -it <aerospike container name> bash -c aql`

You will enter the "AQL" mode of the specified docker container:

[image]

You can then type `help` which will list the available commands and some examples.

There is also the official AQL documentation on Aerospike website: https://docs.aerospike.com/tools/aql.

INSERT example:

```sql
aql> INSERT INTO test.testset (PK, a, b) VALUES ('xyz', 'abc', 123)
```

SELECT example:

```sql
aql> DELETE FROM test.testset WHERE PK='xyz'
```

SHOW NAMESPACES example:

```sql
aql> show namespaces
+------------+
| namespaces |
+------------+
| "test"     |
| "bar"      |
+------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 secs)
```

There is much more you can do with AQL I suggest you read the documentation in the above link.